# When and why was AGGH's runway 06/24 shortened?

Tags: runways, airport-design, closed-runways

[AGGH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honiara_International_Airport) has one runway, 06/24.

When looking at an aerial photo of said runway, I noticed something interesting:

[image: DO look down]

*(Image by Graeme Bartlett at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Henderson_Airfield_runway.jpg).)*

My interest was piqued by seeing what looked suspiciously like a dilapidated additional length of runway, so I went into Google Maps to take a closer look, and it seems that the thing of interest is *indeed* a length of runway in a state of considerable disrepair.  A set of old threshold markings (including the "06") is clearly visible, as well as what appears to be a displaced-threshold chevron.  Right at the end of the pavement, there's what looks like a VOR station:<sup>1</sup>

[image: well, this is interesting]

Runway 06/24 at AGGH is currently 7218 feet (2200 meters) long.  However, if the approximately 3000 feet (915 meters or so) of dilapidated runway to the west-southwest of the current arrival end of runway 06 were included, the runway would be over 10,000 feet long and able to safely accommodate considerably-larger aircraft:

[image: the extra length of runway]

It appears that runway 06/24 was shortened significantly at some point for some reason.  When and why?

---

<sup>1</sup>: It looks like the VOR station (if, indeed, that's what it is) was most likely a later addition taking advantage of the shortened runway (as opposed to having been the original reason for shortening of same), given that, in the first image, the disused segment of runway is already visibly-considerably-degraded, indicating that that photo was taken after said runway segment had already been out of use and no-longer-maintained for a considerable time, but there is no trace of the VOR(?), nor even any signs of construction work at its location, indicating that the looks-like-a-VOR was built there *long* after that stretch of the runway'd been abandoned.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup>: Besides, putting in a new VOR would hardly, in itself, have necessitated removing part of the runway, since there's lots of empty space elsewhere on the airport grounds where one could've been put.

Comment: https://ww2db.com/facility/Henderson_Field/ suggests the runway was *expanded* to the "current length of 2200 meters" in the 1970s.   Meanwhile http://usafunithistory.com/PDF/20-29/29%20AIR%20SERVICE%20GP.pdf suggests the runway was lengthened to 7400 feet during the war.  Haven't found anything about shortening or the abandoned section.

Comment: https://www.nzsappers.org.nz/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/1969-June.pdf has lots of neat descriptions, but suggests the field was only 5400 feet in the 1950s.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know when runway 06/24 at Honiara International Airport, Solomon Islands (AGGH) was shortened, but why it was shortened is possibly because there is a plan to build a second runway, the end of which is proposed to overlap the previous approach end of runway 06. The proposed new (additional) runway is depicted and discussed on this website: [(HERE)](https://canzps.georgetown.edu/2022/12/02/the-changing-face-of-honiara-infrastructure/)

The image below [is found at this site](https://pt-br.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=2230938600569986&set=a.1969037396760109) and **I have drawn a red border around the proposed new runway for clarity**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of sleuthing based on comments and the aerial photograph reveals one or two roadways that may have existed near Honiera International Airport before the runway was *lengthened* more to the *northeast*, remain as remnant "intersections to nowhere", particularly on the north side.

That, and the position of the hangers (usually towards the center) indicates that 3000 feet of the 06 side was abandoned and the 24 side was lengthened by around 5000 feet.

A newer road, going around the 24 end of the runway, seems to replace the older ones. A [topographical](http://maphill.com/solomon-islands/guadalcanal/maps/physical-map/) map of Guadalcanal Island shows rising terrain bearing 240 from the airport, and flat ground or ocean towards the northeast.